# How can I handle the chrome HTTP Authentication popup window in selenium without AutoIT?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, selenium3

I have tried `https://{USERNAME}:{PASSWORD}@xyz.com` pattern to authenticate URL but it doesn't work for me.

Can someone suggest me the best way to handle chrome HTTP authentication popup?

Comment: This question has an answer in following topic: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12892/how-to-send-basic-authentication-headers-in-selenium

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authentication via the URL has been deprecated for a while:

> While this may sound like a thunder from clear skies for Chrome users,
> it is not. The deprecation “order” comes from RFC 3986: ...
>
> 3.2.1.  User Information ... Use of the format "user:password" in the userinfo field is deprecated.
>
> <sub>Source: [Passing basic auth credentials in Google Chrome shows the pop again](https://medium.com/@lmakarov/say-goodbye-to-urls-with-embedded-credentials-b051f6c7b6a3)</sub>

There is an issue on GitHub to get this into WebDriver W3Cspecs: [Missing support for HTTP authentication prompts #385](https://github.com/w3c/webdriver/issues/385).

You could try to use the argument `--disable-blink-features="BlockCredentialedSubresources"` to re-enable basic auth via the URL as described in this answer: [Passing basic auth credentials in Google Chrome shows the pop again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57192562/passing-basic-auth-credentials-in-google-chrome-shows-the-pop-again).

Answer (score 2):

Despite you have chosen Niels answer as correct, I would also suggest a way to work around your issue.

What you're talking about is likely a "basic authentication". The best way to bypass this step is to add [`Authorization`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication) header to HTTP requests which are sent by your browser. To do that you need to set up some proxy which would add mentioned header with the value `Basic userNameEncoded:passEncoded` where `userNameEncoded:passEncoded` is the pair of your credentials encoded in Base64.

You can use some lightweight proxy like [browsermob-proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy). [Here](https://webelement.click/en/http_header_selenium_webdriver_basic_authorization) you can find some examples of how to configure it for Java case. As far as I know the proxy has wrappers for Python and probably some other languages.

**UPD:** Here is the [solution for Python Selenium case](https://www.webelement.click/en/four_simple_steps_to_add_custom_http_headers_in_selenium_webdriver_tests_in_python)